# Arraylist of object find all different property object

Tags: java, arraylist

i have arraylist of objects (Elements) and need to find all elements with different style:

```
ArrayList<Element> = new ArrayList<Element>();

class Element {
    String text;
    Style style;

    public Element() {}
}

class Style {
    String background;
    Integer size;

    public Style() {}
}
```

Comment: So, how have you tried to solve it?

Comment: well, then you need to loop your array and use a if-statement, or you can use the stream api depending on what java version you are using... write a simple unit test and then try to write you application code.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // define elements:
        Element e1 = new Element();
        e1.setText("1. Element");
        e1.setStyle(new Style("#343434", 100));

        Element e2 = new Element();
        e2.setText("2. Element");
        e2.setStyle(new Style("#343411", 100));

        Element e3 = new Element();
        e3.setText("3. Element");
        e3.setStyle(new Style("#343434", 101));

        Element e4 = new Element();
        e4.setText("4. Element");
        e4.setStyle(new Style("#343434", 100));
        // add elements to list:
        list.add(e1);
        list.add(e2);
        list.add(e3);
        list.add(e4);
        // define standard stayl and size
        String backgroundStandard = "#343434";
        Integer sizeStandard = 100;
        // check elements
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            if(!list.get(i).getStyle().getBackground().equals(backgroundStandard)){
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getText() + " has a different background!");
            }
            if(list.get(i).getStyle().getSize() != sizeStandard){
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getText() + " has a different size!");
            }
        }


class Element {
        String text;
        Style style;

        public Element() {}

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public Style getStyle() {
            return style;
        }

        public void setStyle(Style style) {
            this.style = style;
        }


    }

class Style {
        String background;
        Integer size;

        public Style(String background, Integer size) {
            this.background = background;
            this.size = size;
        }

        public String getBackground() {
            return background;
        }

        public void setBackground(String background) {
            this.background = background;
        }

        public Integer getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setSize(Integer size) {
            this.size = size;
        }       

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do not get it wrong, you would use the `Collectors.groupingBy` method such as below:

```
Map<String, List< Element >> counting = elements.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Element::getStyle));
// you should override the compare method inside Style class.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an equal method on class **Style**, which two Style are same if the background is same. On **Main** class I have created an empty arraylist of elemnets, just for putting unique Elements.

Get unique Style:

```
ArrayList<Element> empty = new ArrayList<Element>();

for(Element e : elements)
{
   boolean add = false;
   for(Element em : empty){
      if(em.getStyle().equal(e.getStyle()))
         add = true;
   }
   if(!add)
      empty.add(e);
}
```

Here is full code:

class Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

        Style s1 = new Style("black",1);
        Style s2 = new Style("red",2);
        Style s3 = new Style("black",2);

        Element e1 = new Element("element 1", s1);
        Element e2 = new Element("element 2", s2);
        Element e3 = new Element("element 3", s3);

        elements.add(e1);
        elements.add(e2);
        elements.add(e3);

        ArrayList<Element> empty = new ArrayList<Element>();

        for(Element e : elements)
        {
            boolean add = false;
            for(Element em : empty){
                if(em.getStyle().equal(e.getStyle()))
                    add = true;
            }
            if(!add)
                empty.add(e);
        }

    }
}
```

class Element:

```
public class Element {
    String text;
    Style style;

    public Style getStyle() {
        return style;
    }

    public Element() {}

    public Element(String text, Style style) {
        this.text = text;
        this.style = style;
    }
}
```

class Style:

```
public class Style {
    String background;
    Integer size;

    public Style() {}

    public Style(String background, Integer size) {
        this.background = background;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    public boolean equal(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj instanceof Style)
        {
            Style s = (Style)obj;
            return background.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getBackground());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```